Integrating $\int {x^2 \ln(2x)}\,dx$. Where's my error?
The problem reads:

Given $$\int {u^n \ln(u)}\,du = \frac{u^{n+1}\ln(u)}{n+1} - \frac{u^{n+1}} {(n+1)^2}$$ evaluate the integral $I$, $$\int {x^2 \ln(2x)}\,dx$$

My solution:

We need to find $u$ and $n$ such that $$u^n \ln(u) = x^2 \ln(2x) \tag{1} $$
Let $u = 2x$. Then
$$(2x)^n \ln(2x) = x^2 \ln(2x) \tag{2}$$
$$(2x)^n = x^2 \tag{3}$$
$$\ln((2x)^n) = \ln(x^2) \tag{4}$$
$$n\ln(2x) = 2\ln(x) \tag{5}$$
$$ n = \frac {2\ln(x)} {\ln(2x)} = \frac {\ln(x^2)}  {\ln(2x)} = \log_{2x}(x^2) \tag{6}$$ With $u = 2x$ and $n=\log_{2x}(x^2), $ and $$ n+1 = \log_{2x}(x^2) + \log_{2x}(2x) = \log_{2x}(2x^3) \tag{7}$$ then (substituting into the given equation):
$$ I = \frac {(2x)^{\log_{2x}(2x^3)}\ln(2x)} {\log_{2x}(2x^3)} - \frac{(2x)^{\log_{2x}(2x^3)}}{(\log_{2x}(2x^3))^2} - C \tag8$$
$$ I = \frac {(2x)^{\log_{2x}(2x^3)}}{\log_{2x}(2x^3)}(\ln(2x) - \frac{1}{\log_{2x}(2x^3)}) - C \tag{9}$$ (where $C$ is any real number).

This is obviously not correct, but I can't actually find what I did wrong. I am puzzled. What did I do wrong?

It would be easier to start with $\ln(2x) = \ln 2 + \ln x$.

The mistake is in $(1)$:

We need to find $u$ and $n$ such that $$u^n\ln(u) = x^2 \ln(2x)$$

This is false. Instead, you should be finding $u$ and $n$ such that $$∫u^n\ln(u)du =∫x^2\ln(2x)dx$$.
Your approach should take into account the differentials.

No, this is not the intent of the given integral identity.  You let $u = 2x$, but then when you try to solve $$(2x)^n \ln 2x = x^2 \ln 2x,$$ this leads to a specific value for $x$ for which the above equation is true.  However, $x$ is a variable of integration and must be allowed to take on any value in the domain of the integrand.
Instead, if we let $u = 2x$, then $du = 2 \, dx$, and we find
$$u^n \ln u \, du = (2x)^n (\ln 2x) (2) \, dx = 2^{n+1} x^n \ln 2x \, dx.$$
Thus, with the choice $n = 2$, we have
$$u^2 \ln u \, du = 8 x^2 \ln 2x \, dx,$$
hence
$$8 \int x^2 \ln 2x \, dx = \int u^2 \ln u \, du,$$
and we can use the given formula now.  Then divide the result by $8$.
Alternatively, you may also reason
$$\int x^2 \ln 2x \, dx = \int x^2 (\ln 2 + \ln x) \, dx = \ln 2 \int x^2 \, dx + \int x^2 \ln x \, dx = \frac{\ln 2}{3} x^3 + \int x^2 \ln x \, dx,$$
and now you may apply the given integral identity directly.

"this leads to a specific value for $x$ for which the above equation is true." Why? I thought I was just rearranging to find $n$ in terms of $x$. This shouldn't change the domain, I thought?

I really think the intended solve is the split of $\ln(2x)$. But substitution is a good exercicse too : I would rewrite the integral $\int \frac{(2x)^n}{2^n}\ln(2x)\frac 12d(2x)$, I think it's easier to see the substitution this way.

@BarackBarackBarack $n$ is not a function of $x$, in as much as $n$ is not a function of $u$ in the original integral identity.  Consequently, solving for $n$ in terms of $x$ leads to an integrand for which the given integral identity would not apply.

@zwim Thank you so much, this made me realize my error directly. I was substituting $2x$ into $u$, but not $d(2x)$ into $du$.

You are falling victim to trying to follow the formula too closely. Often when things get that messy something went astray. Perform the substitution you did, and the $$x^{2} = 4u^{2}$$ Integral properties defy your false intuition that you must find u and n to satisfy $$u^{n}ln(u)=x^{2}ln(x)$$ since the 4 make be pulled out then your property can be used.
Also, I assume n is implicitly a real number and not a function. It is easy to shuffle around terms and draw false conclusions. A good reality check is to reassure yourself at your steps everything is what is should be. For example when n became a function of x instead of a real number in your deductions. N being a function results in a totally different formula and makes the above identity invalid since the integral is with respect to x.
